# javax.money.RoundingContextBuilder NoClassDefFoundError

Tags: java, android, java-money

I want to create `javax.money.CurrencyUnit` by using:

```
   public static CurrencyUnit getCurrency() {
    return Monetary.getCurrency("IDR");
   }
```

But, I got error:

```
    java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:  
  at javax.money.RoundingContextBuilder.<init> (RoundingContextBuilder.java:32) 
  at javax.money.RoundingContextBuilder.of (RoundingContextBuilder.java:77) 
  at javax.money.DefaultMonetaryRoundingsSingletonSpi$DefaultCurrencyRounding.<clinit> (DefaultMonetaryRoundingsSingletonSpi.java:266) 
  at javax.money.DefaultMonetaryRoundingsSingletonSpi.<clinit> (DefaultMonetaryRoundingsSingletonSpi.java:43) 
  at javax.money.Monetary.loadMonetaryRoundingsSingletonSpi (Monetary.java:125) 
  at javax.money.Monetary.<clinit> (Monetary.java:54) 
  at id.co.bippo.bidapplication.util.Utils.getCurrency (Utils.java:912)
```

In android with specification:
`Asus ZenFone 5 (ASUS_T00F), 1024MB RAM, Android 4.3`

and `gradle` for money:

```
compile 'javax.money:money-api-bp:1.0.1'
compile 'org.javamoney:moneta-bp:1.1'
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using this

```
compile group: 'javax.money', name: 'money-api', version: '1.0.1'
compile group: 'org.javamoney', name: 'moneta-bp', version: '1.1'
```

Comment: I think ```money-api-bp```, not ```'money-api'``` @Anonymous

Comment: did you try adding this?